# start learning jquery mobile for android

Tags: jquery, android

I would like to use JQUERY mobile in android for better UI views.Could  anyone please let me know where can i start with?

I have no knowledge in jquery so please let me know the basics to advance and how to integrate with android.

Please forward me your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I havent used jquery mobile. But i have used Sencha Touch which is another javascript library used for create mobile web apps. I would suggest that library. They are well documented and their community is pretty good.
http://www.sencha.com

You can later wrap your application using phone gap if you plan to submit to the android market place.

Comment: Thanks blessenm.Need small clarification as whether it is paid library.I am actually looking for free ones.

Comment: Sencha is paid only for commercial projects. If your project is academic or free there is no license required. Jquery mobile maybe good but is new. I have used normal jquery and its pretty easy to use. Most of the libraries have demos inside the package so will make studying easier. Go with the library that suits you the most.